# How to dedupe from front of the array which can only return the limited values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `["this", "is", "my", "text", "this", "is"]` from this I want `["my", "text", "this", "is"]`

My approach is to reverse() the array first, then remove the duplicates and at last reverse() again to its original form.

Code :

```
const limit = 3; // after removed the duplicated only want front 3 values
const arr = [1,2,2,5,1,6]
const dedupeArray = [...new Set(arr.reverse())].reverse();
// dedupeArray = [2,5,1,6]
```

After applying the limit expected output is `[2,5,1]`

But after this, I also want only limited values back, like only starting 3 values if the limit is 3. So my question here, If I already know the limit value before processing, then is there any solution that does not process the whole array, and once I get the limited values, I stop the processing?

Comment: What the logic behind this kind of order like [2,5,1]? Unless we know it can't be put into code.

Comment: dedupeArray value is [2,5,1] which I got from this line `[...new Set(arr.reverse())].reverse()`

Comment: so is that the expected output?

Comment: ok. Then after getting `dedupeArray` you can apply `dedupeArray .slice(0,limit)` to get inteded result

Comment: "*If I already know the limit value before processing, then is there any solution that does not process the whole array*" impossible - you have to filter out the duplicates. And you cannot filter the duplicates without processing the whole array first. For unordered data, If you have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]`  you cannot know that `1` is there twice unless you take the whole array into consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go through the array at least once. There is no way to short circuit the execution.

You could `delete` the value from `Set` if it is already added and `add` it again

And `Set` methods are faster and sublinear compared to the number of elements in the collection.

```js
const array = ["this", "is", "my", "text", "this", "is"],
      set = new Set,
      limit = 3;

for (const v of array) {
  set.delete(v)
  set.add(v)
}

const output = Array.from(set).slice(0, limit)

console.log( output )
```

Comment: Where is the limit value?

Comment: This does not stop the processing as asked in OP

Comment: @ShravanDhar the array has to be processed till the end.

Comment: @adiga, then you should answer the process still need to process till the end instead of providing codes.

Comment: OP has mentioned `solution that does not process the whole array`. Read properly !!

Comment: @adiga, the output is different, but it still loop through all the item in the array to get the result. OP wants to skip the process if the limit is different.

Comment: @ikhvjs it's not possible as far as I know. But, this is a correct solution.

Comment: @adiga, If this is not possible, your answer shoud be not possible because the question is ```is there any solution that does not process the whole array?```

Comment: @ikhvjs no, I don't know any solution with that. This is a compromise. If there is a better solution than this, OP will accept that answer.

Comment: @adiga, I like your solution actually, I think it is just better to let OP understand that his approach is not possible. I saw your updated answer. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is not possible. Consider `[9, 1,2,3,4,5......, 9]`. After uniquifying you'll get `[1,2,3,4....9]`, and slicing gives you `[1,2,3,4]`. But you don't know that the first `9` is to be removed until you see the last `9`.

So you need to iterate the whole array and slice afterwards. Here's how:

You can use a variation of the classic `filter+indexOf` idiom. It's quadratic in time, but for small arrays it doesn't matter much.

```js
a = ["this", "is", "my", "text", "this", "is"]
u = a.filter((x, n) => a.lastIndexOf(x) === n)
console.log(...u)


a = [1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 6]
u = a.filter((x, n) => a.lastIndexOf(x) === n)
console.log(...u)
```

A more verbose and more efficient solution with a `Set`:

```js
a = ["this", "is", "my", "text", "this", "is"]
u = new Set()
for (let x of a) {
    u.delete(x)
    u.add(x)
}


console.log(...u)
```

Comment: Where is the limit value?

Comment: @ikhvjs: I don't know. Where is it?

Comment: @georg [Here is a `limit()`](https://jsbin.com/bocelic/1/edit?js,console) :P

Comment: @VLAZ: I see, like [here](https://github.com/gebrkn/armita/blob/master/index.js#L170)? ;)

Comment: @georg eh, yours seems better than mine.  Much more robust. Pretty nice project! I've been toying around with something similar in my spare time.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the first sequence of unique items in the array, without having to go through the entire array twice.

```js
const limit = 3; // after removed the duplicated only want front 3 values
const arr = [1,2,2,5,1];
let counter = 1;
let newArr = [];

for(let i = arr.length-1; i > 0; i--){
      if( counter < limit+1){
        if(!newArr.includes(arr[i])){
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
      counter++;
    }
  }else {
    break;
  }
}

console.log(newArr.reverse());
```

Comment: @ikhvjs, true, can't use ```break``` statement in ```forEach``` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the limit factor, you can just use `slice`.

```js
const limit = 3; // after removed the duplicated only want front 3 values
const arr = [1,2,2,5,1,6]
const dedupeArray = [...new Set(arr.reverse())].reverse().slice(0, limit);

console.log(dedupeArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

This will stop the processing depending on the limit and give you optional limit passing capabilities.

```js
const arr = [1,2,2,5,1,6];

const getUnique = (arr, limit = arr.length) => {
  const result = new Set([]);
  for (const elem of arr) {
    result.add(elem);
    if (result.size === limit) break;
  }
  return [...result];
}

// without limit
console.log(getUnique(arr))

// with limit
console.log(getUnique(arr, 3))
```

Comment: The result should be `[2,5,1]` not `[1,2,5]` . Please reread the question.

Answer (score -1):

Just simply include the Undescore.js library in your HTML file.

For example:

```js
var arr=[5,2,3,2,1,4,5,4];

// use _.uniq function pass your array and boolean if true then you will get sorted array

console.log( _.uniq(arr,false));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```